# How to self package app for linux

Tags: linux, curl

I am looking for the best solution to package a standalone executable for linux (32 and 64 bits):

I have machine with limited resources, minimal linux installation and no package manager on it. I'm trying to install curl but it's a nightmare to do it because of missing dependencies or wrong dependencies version.

On curl website, they propose an executable curl version which contains all dependencies, it's working perfectly except it's not the last version.

Do you know how I could do this for all kinds of software?

Comment: Are you trying to compile a binary of your own software that you wrote, or are you looking for a solution to install 3rd-party programs on your unnamed Linux distro with no package manager? If it's the latter, you've got an uphill battle explaining how tech support for Mystery Linux is a valid programming question.

Comment: Download the latest source code, compile to an executable. Bam.